# code for split button in tinymce not working in wordpress 3.9 version?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce-4

I have code for php file as under

```
class TinyMCE_Buttons {
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array(&$this,'init') );
}
function init() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;     
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {  
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array(&$this, 'add_plugin') );  
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array(&$this,'register_button') ); 

    }  
}  
function add_plugin($plugin_array) {  
   $plugin_array['shortcodes'] = SHORTCODES_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/tinymce.js';
   return $plugin_array; 
}
function register_button($buttons) {  
   array_push($buttons, "shortcodes_button");
   return $buttons; 
}   
}
$shortcode = new TinyMCE_Buttons;
```

this is my .js file

```
(function() {   
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce', {
    init : function(ed, url){
        tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce.theurl = url;
    },
    createControl : function(btn, e) {
        if ( btn == "shortcodes_button" ) {
            var a = this;   
            var btn = e.createSplitButton('symple_button', {
                title: "Insert Shortcode",
                image: tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce.theurl +"/shortcodes.png",
                icons: false,
            });
            btn.onRenderMenu.add(function (c, b) {

                b.add({title : 'Shortcodes', 'class' : 'mceMenuItemTitle'}).setDisabled(1);

                // Columns
                c = b.addMenu({title:"Columns"});
// add more menu and cloase file
```

Its not worked in tinymce4.x version also not gives any error.
any solution accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *init* and *createControl* callbacks are no longer called for the *Plugin* object.

Secondly, you need to call the *addButton* function on the *Editor* object.

A proposed solution could work like this (taking code from your post above):

```
(function() {   
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce', function (editor, url) {
    tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce.theurl = url;

    var btn = editor.addButton('symple_button', {
        type: "splitbutton",
        title: "Insert Shortcode",
        image: tinymce.plugins.ShortcodeMce.theurl +"/shortcodes.png",
        icons: false,
        menu: [
            { title: "Shortcodes", classes: "mceMenuItemTitle", disabled: true }
        ]
    });
```

Here's the reference of the *Button* interface in TinyMCE API 4.x: [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.Button](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aclass.tinymce.ui.Button)

Comment: Kamil Waheed @ I already found this question's answer but now I got new problem the link is :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265474/listbox-return-wrong-value-in-wordpress3-9

Comment: still some confusion that where and how to use addButton function ?